# How to properly render a Calendar view title in a month display?

Tags: views, datetime

I have a calendar view set up as shown in these screen shots. Everything is working nicely, except the title. I'd like the title to be only the month, not the first of the month.

[image]
([larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbxEH.png))

That is, instead of the below screen shot reading December 1, 2014, I'd like it to render only December 2014 (omitting the "1st").

[image]
([larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Id7.png))

Is there an answer that I'm missing in the Add Header area?

[image]
([larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwY88.png))

**Update**: Contextual Filter
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the date module that causes this issue. I'm not sure if the latest version of the module resolves it or not. If it doesn't, then the workaround in #20 in the thread at https://www.drupal.org/node/2294973 will fix the issue.

Comment: Can confirm that upgrading to 7.x-2.9-rc1 from 7.x-2.8 resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can use a validation function (with your contextual filter) ... there you will be able to adjust the title with php date functions (formatting the date as you want)

Comment: I updated my question to include a shot of the contextual filter. The Granularity is already at a Month. Should I select the date again in Fields and format that additional date to Month only?

Comment: could work maybe (i dont really know this kind of view) ... you should try different things ... If you hide the date and only show the month maybe it could to the trick but i don't know how views handles the title for calendar

Comment: If you know php you could create a custom module to alter the view at a certain pont and write your own title